# Starting Tomcat in Eclipse Indigo WTP works fine until timeout shuts in down again

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-indigo, eclipse-wtp

After deploying/starting/stopping my Tomcat 7 server with Eclipse Indigo WTP perfectly well for weeks now, I've suddenly run into a problem whereby the Eclipse editor shuts down my server because it thinks it wasn't able to start it properly when in fact it did. I have a full logging console which confirms that it has started and I can access the web application I'm building. It seems the Eclipse editor thinks there is a problem when there isn't one!

Here's the error message:

> Server Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost was unable to start within 45
>   seconds. If the server requires more time, try increasing the timeout
>   in the server editor.

I should add that my application starts up in less than 5 seconds, I've tried running `eclipse - clean`, I've tried deleting the server configuration from within Eclipse and reconfiguring it... what else can I try?

Answer (score 1):

I've been able to solve this by changing the HTTP listen port from within Eclipse to something different. It looks like there must have been a strange port conflict of some sort at the time. Ports can be modified in the server overview page in the *Ports* section (double click the configured server in the Eclipse *Servers* tab and expand the *Ports* section there).

Another way is to kill the process that may be running on the port in question. This is sometimes necessary when Eclipse crashes and somehow leaves the server process running.  A process can be terminated in *Windows* with the following (assuming the HTTP port is 8080 in this example):

```
netstat -a -o -n | findstr 0.0.0.0:8080
```

This is to determine the process ID and you should see something like this:

```
TCP    0.0.0.0:8080           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       3028
```

The process ID is the last number and you can kill that like so:

```
taskkill /F /PID 3028
```